# Need help looping through query result

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

## Model

```
    $data   =   array();
    $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id'); 

    $q = $this->db->get_where('cust_orders', array('cust_id' => $id));


        foreach ($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data['id'] = $row->cust_id; 
            $data['orders'] = $row->cart; 

        }
            return $data;
```

## Controller

Passes the `data` to the view

## View

```
<?php foreach($_orders as $key => $item) : ?>
<tr>

    <td>
    <?php 
        $price = $item['price']; #change this to order status 

        switch ($price) 
        {
        case (64); $UPSTrack = '1Z12345E1512345676'; #Shipped add tracking number
              echo 'Shipped <br> <a href="http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums='.$UPSTrack.'">Track My Order</a>'; 
              break;

        case (88);
              echo 'Shipped'; 
              break;

        default;
              echo 'Processing'; 
              break;
        }
    ?>

    </td>




    <td>
    <?php foreach ($item['options'] as $option => $value) 
            {
            echo '<span class="option">'.$option . ': </span> <span class="options">' . $value . '</span>';
            } 
    ?>
    </td>


    <td><?php echo $item['id']; ?></td>

    <td><?php echo $item['qty'];  ?></td>

    <td><?php echo number_format($item['price'],2); ?></td>

</tr>    



<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Options is an ARRAY**

Contains a `foreach` which loops through the `array` contained in the variable `$data['orders'] = $row->cart;`

In the database I am looking up the `cust_orders` table by `cust_id` A customer may have more than `1` row meaning multiple orders.

The problem is that I am only looping through the last row. I need to loop through all rows where `cust_id` is = to `$session_id`.

I feel the problem is in my `MODEL` because if I change  `$data['id'] = $row->cust_id;` to  `echo $row->cust_id;' I am able to see all of the rows which match the customers id, but it breaks my`foreach` code.

How do I properly assign the `values` returned in the `MODEL` query so that all cust_orders == to `$session_id` are displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are overwrite your array with each customer value, so you need multidimensional array.

It should be like below

**EDIT: Change your foreach in your model as below**

```
   foreach ($q->result() as $row)
    {
        $data['id'] = $row->cust_id; 
        $data['orders'][] = $row->cart; 

    }
```

Comment: I see  but I am using PHP `Shortcode` So how would I put your code in? `<?php $data[] = array( : ?>` and `<?php end $data[]; ?>` I will update my `VIEW` to show my code.

Comment: can you post your original shortcode code ?? i can reformat it

Comment: Hey thanks GBD, I posted up the shortcode in my `VIEW` please take a look

Comment: The shortcode is in the `VIEW` and also note that `cart` is an  array which is `unserialize` in the `VIEW` before the `foreach`

Comment: See my edited answer. you need to change your code into model

Comment: Ok but i get an error `unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` and if i remove unserialize in the view i get ` Illegal string offset '<for each var in view>'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17764/discussion-between-fabio-and-gbd)